# msyql sorting table based on a field but ignored number

Tags: mysql

I want to sort a table in mysql based on 2 fields.

first field is called type. A type consist of 3 characters. Example ADG, ADJ, CC1, CC2, etc. But I want to ignore if the third character is number.

second field is called code, A code consist of 3 characters of numbers only.

I want to sort so that it will display like below,

```
ADG 001
ADG 002
ADG 003
ADJ 001
ADJ 002
ADJ 003
CC2 001
CC3 002
CC1 003
CC0 004
```

see example above, ADJ comes after ADG but CCx where x is number, will only sort based on CC. Ignored the number

Is that possible to do it using mysql select?

if I am using

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY type ASC, code ASC
```

above select is worked only for ADG and ADJ but not with CCx

```
ADG 001
ADG 002
ADG 003
ADJ 001
ADJ 002
ADJ 003
CC0 004
CC1 003
CC2 001
CC3 002
```

on the other hand, when using

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY SUBSTR(type, 1, 1) ASC, code ASC
```

it works for CCx but not working with ADG and ADJ

```
ADG 001
ADJ 001
ADG 002
ADJ 002
ADG 003
ADJ 003
CC2 001
CC3 002
CC1 003
CC0 004
```

Comment: We have different definitions of 'working', I guess.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e7dd77/1

Comment: I found something like this, SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE(type, '[0-9]', '') ASC, code ASC and seemed to work fine. But is it working for php 5.6? since I tested only on mysql 8.0 and what would be with the performance?

Comment: Functions cannot use indexes, so, compared with normalisation, all solutions will be suboptimal.

Comment: Incidentally, there's really no point storing the zeros in 001,002, etc.